# Storing strings

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to write a code which stores strings in an array. I'm trying to do it with char* but I couldn't achieve. I search the net but couldn't find an answer. I've tried the code below, but it didn't compile.I use string stream because at some point I need to concatenate a string with an integer.

```
stringstream asd;
asd<<"my name is"<<5;
string s = asd.str();
char *s1 = s;
```

Comment: Don't use raw `char *` in C++ unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Where's the array? With the given code, the current answers (suggesting a call to `c_str()`) will fail terribly if the array outlives `s`.

Comment: "I'm trying to write a code which stores strings in an array"? *Why*?

Comment: @Johnsyweb I will use that string if correspont array element called and I will print it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > I'm trying to write a code which stores strings in an array.

Well, first you'll need an arary of strings. I don't like using naked arrays, so I use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> myStrings;
```

But, I understand you have to use an array, so we'll use an array instead:

```
// I hope 20 is enough, but not too many.
std::string myStrings[20];
int j = 0;
```

> > I use string stream because ...

Okay, we'll use stringstream:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "Hello, Agent " << 99;
//myStrings.push_back(s.str()); // How *I* would have done it.
myStrings[j++] = s.str(); // How *you* have to do it.
```

That gets us *one* string, but you want an array of them:

```
for(int i = 3; i < 11; i+=2) {
  s.str(""); // clear out old value
  s << i << " is a" << (i==9?" very ":"n ") << "odd prime.";
  //myStrings.push_back(s.str());
  myStrings[j++] = s.str();
}
```

Now you have an array of strings.

Complete, tested program:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  // I hope 20 is enough, but not too many.
  std::string myStrings[20];
  int j = 0;

  std::stringstream s;
  s << "Hello, Agent " << 99;
  //myStrings.push_back(s.str()); // How *I* would have done it.
  myStrings[j++] = s.str(); // How *you* have to do it.

  for(int i = 3; i < 11; i+=2) {
    s.str(""); // clear out old value
    s << i << " is a" << (i==9?" very ":"n ") << "odd prime.";
    //myStrings.push_back(s.str());
    myStrings[j++] = s.str();
  }

  // Now we have an array of strings, what to do with them?
  // Let's print them.
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    std::cout << myStrings[j] << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I need an dynamic array, like user enter 21th string, I should create a new array with the same name whose size is bigger.

Comment: May I suggest that you get your program working with a fixed-size array first, then try to add dynamic arrays later. If (but only if) you don't figure out how dynamic arrays work on your own, come back and ask another question.

Comment: If you want a dynamic array use a vector as @Rob is showing you.

Comment: @Robᵩ I couldn't create an array kind of string a = new string[4];

Comment: @user1305058. I'm not surprised that you can't create a dynamic array. That's why I suggest you get your program working first with a fixed-size array. Only after you have that much working perfectly, then replace your fixed-size array with a dynamic array.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
vector<string> string_array;
stringstream asd;
asd<<"my name is"<<5;
string_array.push_back(asd.str());
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use a vector.

Comment: You should put that in the question. Also, does that mean this is homework? You should tag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *s1 = s;
```

Is illegal. You either need:

```
const char *s1 = s.c_str();
```

if you're not set on `char*`, or you'll need to allocate a new `char*` and use `strcpy` to copy the contents from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to

```
char const* s1 = s.c_str();
```

because a pointer to char can't store a string object, only a pointer to char, which is what c_str() returns.

Comment: Are you sure this will compile?

Comment: `c_str` returns a `const char*`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Technically the pointer can point to the object, no? Although it is possible I'm too used to C# at this point.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth obviously, sry! :)

Comment: @Shingetsu a pointer can also point to 0x000000. It's not useful though.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore a pointer can point to `0x000000` where a `const char*` will exist. But does const reflect on the binary code?

Comment: @Shingetsu There's no binary code, because that only exists *if* the code compiles.

Comment: @Shingetsu the code won't compile, and if it does, it doesn't mean it makes sense. If you try to modify the contents of the char*, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore just checked, the code does not compile. Fixed the code to above. Code does compile and work. That is to say the information stays intact.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore after some more testing I found the only way to get a char* result is to literally iterate the string. The reason I was trying to get to that result was because I didn't want the OP not to be able to modify the contents (because that's the general reason you might want to get it in an array).

Comment: @Shingetsu that's not the only way.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore what other ways are there? I'm generally new in the programming world (about 2 years now, but only 1 year of active OO), and I'm working in C# now (passed from assembler to C to C++ to java to lisp to C#). Please tell me what other ways are available as I'm thoroughly interested in algorithms in the low level, as they help to understand high level ones.

Comment: @Shingetsu see the other answers, including mine, with strcpy.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the char * directly.  I would wrap it in something like the template below.  You can override the operators you need to do any more operations (example, I would make data a private member, and override the operators to make the data print out cleanly).  I did the assignment operator just to demonstrate how clean that could make code.

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

template<size_t size>
class SaferChar
{
public:

  SaferChar & operator=(string const & other)
  {
    strncpy(data, other.c_str(), size);

    return *this;
  }

  char data[size];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  SaferChar<10> safeChar;
  std::string String("Testing");


  safeChar = String.c_str();

  printf("%s\n", safeChar.data);

  return 0;
}
```